# Using Viewpager to display images from web but it is not showing me, Someone help me to solve this issue

Tags: java, android

I don't have any errors but still my data is not showing in android emulator, I passed it in mainactivity but still it displays blank screen,Someone help me to solve this issue. I gave internet permission to display images. Is this androidx jetpack problem because it is happening for me many times while getting information from web .Check out the code below

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private String[] imageUrls = {"https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300","https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: onCreate method executing");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewAdapter adapter = new ViewAdapter(this,imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

ViewAdapter

```
public class ViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "ViewAdapter";
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] imageUrls;

    public ViewAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        mContext = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrls[position]).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
        Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem: returning view");
        return imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
      container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}

 Android manifest

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause:** You forgot to add the imageView into the containing View in which the imageView will be shown.

**Solution:** Change your code to

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
    
    // Add this line
    container.addView(imageView);
    
    Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem: returning view");
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028718/getting-null-reference-for-viewpager-in-android-ive-attached-my-database-check

Comment: Check the above question bro Again I gor null reference in viewpager, if possible answer me bro